# Oozie-- java: command not found - shell action

Tags: shell, hadoop, oozie

I am running a java program from a shell script through Oozie and I get the below error

```
java: command not found
```

When I run the shell script from the edge node I do not find any issues and the java class runs without any error and I get the desired output also. However it is the oozie job that fails to run the java command.

All other actions in oozie are executed porperly but when it encounters the `java` line, it throws the afore said error. I understand that all the nodes in the Hadoop cluster will have Java installed, then why do I get this error?
Below is the java command that I have in my shell script

```
...
...    
java -cp $LOCAL_DIR/libs/integration-tools.jar com.audit.reporting.GenerateExcelReport $LOCAL_DIR/input.txt $LOCAL_DIR/
...
```

Please provide your thoughts.

Comment: `java: command not found` generally indicates that your `PATH` does not include the location of the `java` command. Compare `echo "$PATH"` in this environment to `echo "$PATH"` in an environment where the JVM can be successfully invoked.

Comment: ...certainly, Java may be *installed*, but the question is whether the location where it's installed is *currently in the PATH for the process at hand*. Many operating systems install the JVM in a location like `/usr/lib/jvm/java8-jre-bin` or such, and daemons may not have that location (whatever the exact relevant/correct location is) in their PATH.

Comment: By the way -- all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the operating system or shell, whereas names with at least one lowercase character are reserved for application use, to prevent applications from overwriting meaningful names by mistake. See the relevant POSIX specification at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Issue Fixed"

I talked with my DevOps later and found that the classpath for Java was not set in few datanodes in the Cluster. This was stopping the shell action to invoke the JVM at those datanodes.
After fixing the Classpath, the job ran successfully.
All the comments mentioned by @Charles Duffy are valid.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have your integration-tools.jar along with your code jar in hdfs location? 
Oozie can choose any node to run the java action and it will look for these jar at that location.

Comment: This appears to be the JVM itself not being found, rather than a JAR not being found.

Comment: I second @CharlesDuffy, as the error clearly says that `java: command found` which is a clear indication of either java not being installed or the location of java is not set in classpath.